# Axlsx - Warning while opening a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, axlsx

I was working on generating some excel reports and those sheets contains lot of data. I cannot use below line as I am not going in linear way

```
worksheet.add_row [array_of_data]
```

For this I first initialize a row in the below way

```
worksheet.add_row Array.new(maxmimum_columns, nil)
```

Then updated the value accordingly. Here 'maxmimum_columns' is calculated dynamically. I found that when this value becomes large and tries to open file in excel then while opening file I encounter a warning that file might have some virus. What should I do? I am unable to find some proper documentation. The maximum_colmns is less then the maximum columns of excel 2010 [16384](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried putting all your data in a plain array instead, and inspecting it?

Comment: Yah I already tried it. Event the above code is already creating a plain array of max col. size.